# How to have more than one type in ML?

Tags: sml, ml

Is it possible in ML to allow a variable in ML to have more than one type?

For instance, If I want a node in a tree to only be an int or a string.

```
Node of int * string
```

I tried this but it just results in a tuple type of (int, string). I don't want it to be a tuple, just either an int or a string. Is this allowed?

Comment: This is called a "union type" afaik. Idk if ML has them, but that's what you could search for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, the feature you're looking for is union types. I believe the syntax for them in SML is:

```
datatype Node = IntNode of int
              | StringNode of string
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to generalise @TimDestan's great answer a bit: the general idea of a value having *either* one type *or* the other can be encoded in a type. E.g., in Haskell and Scala we have the `Either` type which can hold values of two different types exclusively. We can define the same in SML:

```
datatype ('a, 'b) either = Left of 'a | Right of 'b
```

Now you can encode your node as:

```
Node of (int, string) either
```

And nodes can be constructed like:

```
Node (Left 1)
Node (Right "hello")
```

This is a bit more lightweight than defining a custom sum type for this case specifically.